# Write specific JSON structure to .json file in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have the following Python code:

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = requests.get('https://www.perfectimprints.com/custom-promos/20492/Beach-Balls.html')
source = BeautifulSoup(url.text, 'html.parser')

products = source.find_all('div', class_="product_wrapper")

def get_product_details(product):
  product_name = product.find('div', class_="product_name").a.text
  sku = product.find('div', class_="product_sku").text
  product_link = product.find('div', class_="product_image_wrapper").find("a")["href"]
  src = product.find('div', class_="product_image_wrapper").find('a').find("img")["src"]
  return {
      "title": product_name,
      "link": product_link,
      "sku": sku,
      "src": src
  }

all_products = [get_product_details(product) for product in products]

with open("products.json", "w") as write_file:
  json.dump(all_products, write_file)

print("Success")
```

This code works perfectly as written. The problem is I want the structure instead of

```
[
  {
    "title": "12\" Beach Ball",
    "link": "/promos/PI-255-751/12-Beach-Ball.html?cid=20492",
    "sku": "  \n\t\t\t\t#PI-255-751\n\t\t\t",
    "src": "https://12f598f3b6e7e912e4cd-a182d9508ed57781ad8837d0e4f7a945.ssl.cf5.rackcdn.com/thumb/751_group.jpg"
  },
]
```

I want it to be:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "title": "12\" Beach Ball",
      "link": "/promos/PI-255-751/12-Beach-Ball.html?cid=20492",
      "sku": "  \n\t\t\t\t#PI-255-751\n\t\t\t",
      "src": "https://12f598f3b6e7e912e4cd-a182d9508ed57781ad8837d0e4f7a945.ssl.cf5.rackcdn.com/thumb/751_group.jpg"
    },
  ]
}
```

Here's a link to what I have working in Repl.it, just so you don't have to set up your own: https://repl.it/repls/AttractiveDimpledTheory

Side note: Would love to also be able to remove all of the `\n` and `\t` in the `sku`s if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you're dumping your `all_products` list directly to JSON:

```
with open("products.json", "w") as write_file:
    json.dump(all_products, write_file)
```

The JSON you want just has that list in an object. Something like

```
with open("products.json", "w") as write_file:
    json.dump({'items': all_products}, write_file)
```

should do what you want.

Generally speaking there's a 1:1 relationship between your Python data structure and the JSON it generates. If you build the right Python data structure you'll get the right JSON. Here we're using a `dict` (which maps to a JSON object) to wrap your existing `list` (which maps to a JSON array).

> Side note: Would love to also be able to remove all of the `\n` and `\t` in the `sku`s if possible.

Assuming you also want to remove spaces, you can just use [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20strip#str.strip), which strips whitespace by default:

```
return {
    "title": product_name,
    "link": product_link,
    "sku": sku.strip(),  # <-- here
    "src": src
}
```

Comment: I seriously overcomplicated that. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you @Chris. I needed to wait the mandatory 2 minutes. Further question regarding the `.string()` function. What stripping when I don't want to strip all of the whitespace. For example: I have something similar to get the category name i.e. `Beach Balls` but the data I got from python is `\n\t\t\t\t\t\tBeach Balls`. As you'd imagine, I want to keep the spacing there.

Comment: You mean you want to keep the space between `Beach` and `Balls`? That should happen by default. `str.strip()` only removes leading and trailing characters.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to come back and reply that I figured that. Thanks!